# Git clone with HTTP code 504 return

Tags: git, http, github

I would like to ask about Git clone error. 
Unfortunately, my github has shown below error and can not checkout recently .

> Cloning into `MapProject-ios`...
>   error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 504
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Is there anybody has a point on this case ?
Please support me! Thank you so much

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or proxy server?

Comment: Is your remote set correctly? (check output of ```git remote -v```)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm behind a proxy . But other git hub is working fine. 
Only this git link can not clone

Comment: @DanielArndt : remote set is correctly. 
But I'm using https not SSH

Comment: This may be a silly question, but are the others using ssh? :)

Comment: @DanielArndt : ssh is OK. 
I just confusing that all of others git link has working fine some days ago. 
But suddenly it's not working now. 
Why only occurred with HTTP ? That's my confusing

Comment: Can you share the github link? I want try to clone it in my local pc.

Answer (score 2):

two possible workarounds:

1) Check your remote url with:

```
git remote -v
```

and fix it with:

```
git remote set-url origin <newurl>
```

2) You can increase you git buffer size to largest individual file size of your repo by(assuming size is an issue)

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

try updating your git, if any of these didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If other GitHub repo are working fine (with https url), then the issue might be on GitHub itself.

Either try and contact GitHub support directly (to check with them if that particular repo has any issue)

Or try and fork that repo (on the server side, with the web GUI), just to test if you can clone that fork.